# Comparing two dictionary with DateTime Key and DateTime Value to get the available doctor Slots in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datetime, datetime-comparison

I have listed some doctor slots which are stored in a Dictionary as DateTime Key as Start Time and DateTime Value as End Time. I have another Dictionary with DateTime Key and DateTime Value to contain some booked or already scheduled times. Now how can I compare these two dictionaries to get my available or free slots? Code for doctor slots and booked slots are given below:

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> GetDoctorSlots()
{
    var doctorSlots = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();

    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
    var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(23, 30, 0);

    var start = startTime;

    while (start <= endTime)
    {
        var end = start.AddMinutes(30);
        doctorSlots.Add(start, end);
        start = end;
    }

    return doctorSlots;
}
    
private Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> GetScheduledSlots(DateTime studyDate, int? orgId)
{            
    var appointments = (from schedule in _context.PmrSchedules
                        join scheduleDtl in _context.PmrScheduledtls on schedule.ScheduleId equals scheduleDtl.ScheduleId
                        where schedule.IsActive == true
                            && scheduleDtl.IsActive == true
                            && schedule.ScheduleDt.Year == studyDate.Year
                            && schedule.ScheduleDt.Month == studyDate.Month
                            && schedule.ScheduleDt.Day == studyDate.Day
                            && schedule.OrgId == orgId
                        select scheduleDtl).ToList();

    var scheduledSlots = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();

    foreach (var schedule in appointments)
    {
        if (schedule.StartTime == null || schedule.EndTime == null)
            continue;

        var start = (DateTime)schedule.StartTime;
        var end = (DateTime)schedule.EndTime;

        scheduledSlots.Add(start, end);
    }

    scheduledSlots = scheduledSlots.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Date).ThenBy(a => a.Key.Hour).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);            

    return scheduledSlots;
}

private Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> GetAvailableSlots(DateTime studyDate, int? orgId)
{
    var doctorSlots = GetDoctorSlots();
    var scheduledSlots = GetScheduledSlots(studyDate, orgId);

    // COMPARE doctorSlots WITH scheduledSlots

    return RESULT;
}
```

Now I would like to compare the **doctorSlots** dictionary with **scheduledSlots** to get the available slots from doctorSlots. The problem is **scheduledSlots** can have objects which does not have in the doctorSlots. In that case I need to compare each start and end time of scheduledSlots with doctorSlots. Can anyone give me suggestions how can I do this?

Comment: So basically you have a set of date ranges and almost anything you do with them will require iterating over them in order, which makes having them in a dictionary awkward.  It would be better to create a `DateRange` type that's composed of a start and end date (or state date and timespan)  then implement `IComparable` and store them in a sorted data structure like a `SortedSet`

Comment: Yeah... I agree with juharr - this data storage mechanism you've devised is awkward. Think about the calenadar (paper) on your wall. It shows a month as an array of slots and you can see "Holiday, Holiday, Holiday" next week on the Tue/Wed/Thu so you know you're not available for those slots. It is NOT a list of entries like "21st - dentist" "25th - 27th holiday", "28th piano recital" that must be searched when your buddy says "coming to my party on the 26th"? -> "hangon while I enumerate this list and work out if your 26th is between any of the ranges...". No,you just "lookup 26th..Oh..sorry"